# surface area calculation

Tags: opengl, area

I use glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,...) to draw harmonic wave.
I would like to know the order in which the surfaces (triangles?) are generated by openGL while rendering based on the vertices
and in such a way calculate the surface area?
Can I do it and if yes how.

---

I will try to explain it better

I have 2D array of values and perform uv-mapping on it.( i generate harmonic wave)
and draw the surface accepted using glDrawArrays.
I want to calculate the surface area,which i visualize.
I think I should "translate" the problem to be easier for such calculation by creating a grid of triangles ,
which is suitable for points drawing - this will simplify my calculation.

Comment: You want to calculate the area of the surfaces (which is a number) using OpenGL rendering? How would you like to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,...) to draw harmonic wave.

Points have no surface.

> I would like to know the order in which the surfaces (triangles?) are generated by openGL while rendering based on the vertices and in such a way calculate the surface area? Can I do it and if yes how.

OpenGL doesn't generate traiangles. It rasterizes the triangles you send it. In the very same order in which you specify them. `glDrawArrays(mode, first, count)` *behaves* exactly like

```
myDrawArrays(GLenum mode, GLuint first, GLuint count)
{
    GLuint *indices = malloc(count * sizeof(GLuint));
    /* just assume malloc never fails, OpenGL doesn't have to alloc here, of course) */
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        indices[i] = first + i;
    glDrawElements(mode, count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
    free(indices);
}
```

The primitives are rasterized in the order they are specified.

So you want to know a surface area, but are drawing points. As already told, points (mathematically) have no surface. However they cover at least one (sub-)pixel. So could it be that you actually want to know the *pixel coverage*?

Then OpenGL provides you a method called "occlusion query" using which it returns you, how many (screen/framebuffer) pixels got touched by drawing the primitives within the query.

http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/occlusion_query.txt

Comment: @Yakov: I still don't clearly understand what you want to do? Do you use the wave as a distortion of a grid or something like that? Anyway: OpenGL deals only with drawing stuff. It's not some geometry library of some kind and can't help you there. Your problem actually is rooted in differential geometry, so I'd apply the methods of differential calculus to solve the problem. Specifically you should differentiate your sampling function and integrate the diffential surface elements. http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/wdj/teach/sm221_surface_area1.html

Answer (score 1):

The geometry shading stage contains the information about drawn polygon, so you can calculate the surface amount from there. In order to get the sum of it you can render into 1x1 R_32F framebuffer object with additive blending, then read the value into system memory.